# How to replace a exact method call in a fluent api using java assist?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, javassist

I need to replace a method call inside java method.

Consider a scenario :

```
public void enterCatle(){

    if(PaltformRuntime.returnSuggestion()){

        System.out.println("entered into the castle");
    }
}
```

I need to replace a `returnSuggestion()` with some other method call.I am able to achieve this by overriding the `edit(MethodCall m)` in the 
`Expression editor of java assist`.

But there is a scenario as follows.

```
public void enterCatle(){   
    if(PaltformRuntime.returnSuggestion() && ElementRegistry.returnSuggestion()){

        System.out.println("entered into the castle");
    }
}
```

Here inside the `enterCatle()` in the if statement there are 2 `returnSuggestion()` from different classes. What I need is to replace the first `returnSuggestion()` alone.

I tried to identify the exact method call to replace by conditions like `m.getLineNumber()` `m.where().getName()` with this things I am able to narrow down to the particular method and exact line number. Now the problem is, if the same method is used twice in the same line, both get replaced.

How can I identify the exact method to replace? Is there any way to get the context of the method call like which position the method call is placed so that I can map by java assist.
or is there any other approach for this scenario?

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:bytecode] and [tag:instrumentation] so you shouldn’t be dealing with expressions which are source code artifacts, not to speak of line numbers. Besides that, if you think that one method invocation is the right one and the other the wrong one, you should be able to tell which makes one of them the right one compared to the other. If you can’t express that as a clear condition, the task description itself is flawed and can’t be fixed on the code size.

Comment: So the two methods differ in receiver type and return type. In that case, if you process the class using an API dealing with bytecode instructions rather than source code, it’s quite easy to tell these methods apart as every invocation instruction is associated with a resolved target method and these methods are considered to be entirely different, just happen to have the same name.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your response. I have edited my question according to the exact scenario that I need. Here both the returnSuggestion() returns boolean. I need to replace the only first call to returnSuggestion(). Is there any way to achieve it ?

Comment: In principle, it should be possibly; as said, the receiver type is part of the information associated with an invocation instruction. Unfortunately, I’m not using Javassist, so I can’t go into detail regarding this specific library, but I think [`CodeConverter.redirectMethodCall`](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/CodeConverter.html#redirectMethodCall-javassist.CtMethod-javassist.CtMethod-), which receives the old method as `CtMethod` instance, which knows its declaring class, could be the way to go.